# wf expression editor

Tags: visual-studio-2010, workflow-foundation

Is there way to set the default window of expression editor in WF designer of visual studio? Every time it shows up it is too small and I need to resize it. It is so unusefull!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not from anything I've seen.

I'd suggest [opening up a connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/), or possibly asking the [WOVS people](http://wovs.com/) to create an extension.